# Код работает в Program.cs и не работает в Class1.cs

Tags: c#

Обнаружил, что в классе кусок кода не работает, хотя все библиотеки подключены. Прикрепил скрины:

[image: Внутри программы]

[image: Внутри класса]

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: и текстом код заодно вставь

Comment: Код необходимо вставлять картинками, а не прикладывать изображениями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка из-за несоответствия имен метода и свойств пространств имен.

Переименуйте метод, и ошибка уйдет.

Тут скорее не рекурсия, а просто в пространстве имен класс `Screen` и метод ваш `Screen` имеют одинаковое название. И IDE не может понять что вы там имели веду. Всегда перед тем как постить вопрос, наведите на ошибку и почитайте что там написано, может просто опечатка.

```
class Class1
{
    public void CreateScreen()
    {
        Graphics graph = null;

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);

        bmp.Save("filename.png");
    }
}
```

**Удачи в программировании!**

**SeeSharp**

Comment: Я про красные волнистые линии, в `Program` их нет, а в `Class` есть

Comment: @user321409 а ты читал что там написано?

Comment: "Class1.Screen() является метод, который недопустим в данном контексте" в обеих случаях

Comment: @user321409 правил ответ

Comment: @user321409 всегда пожалуйста. Галочка справа, +1 к ответу тоже было бы не плохо. Удачи!